# Clear all comments in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Tried to write a Excel VBA code to set background picture and clear all comments in all sheets. For some reason, i have to run the code twice in order to clear all comments. When I run the code first time, there are some comments left.

Can you let me know what's wrong with the code? Thanks.

```
Sub Set_Draft()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
WS_Count = Worksheets.Count
For I = 1 To WS_Count
    Worksheets(I).Activate
    ActiveSheet.SetBackgroundPicture "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\DRAFT Watermark.PNG"
    ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearComments
Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and is a little more efficient:

```
Sub Set_Draft()

  Dim WS As Worksheet

  For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

     WS.SetBackgroundPicture "G:\BEKDocs\Images to Post\Graphics\BBTMath.jpg"
     WS.Cells.ClearComments

  Next WS

End Sub 'Set_Draft
```

HTH